# Polymer: iron-dropdown change attribute issue

Tags: jquery, attributes, polymer, dropdown

I have a simple iron-dropdown element:

```
<iron-dropdown id="droplist" horizontal-offset="26" vertical-align="top">
     <ul class="dropdown-content">
           <li>1</li>
           <li>2</li>
           <li>3</li>
           ...
     </ul>
</iron-dropdown>
```

I would change the property vertical-align into "bottom" when dropdown element is 200px from the bottom of the page; so I do this:

```
if(($(window).height() - $(event.target).offset().top) < 200)
    $('#droplist').attr("vertical-align", "bottom");

document.querySelector('#droplist').open();
```

but it doesn't work correctly; I see dropdown always like "top" attribute, so the function doesn't change vertical-align.
If, in the function, I change the attribute with

```
$('#droplist').attr("horizontal-offset", "60");
```

it works correctly; how is it possible??

Comment: I don't think jquery can be used. Try the dom manipulation apis provided by polymer https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html

Comment: I try them but I have the same result...

Comment: If you post polymer code that is not working, someone might be help you.

Comment: that is the code not working....